# When is it okay to bottle?

Tags: fermentation

I've brewed literally dozens of Beer House brewkits, but I'm waiting on a Winterfest Ale kit that just won't seem to completely stop secondary fermentation...every other time I made these kits, fermenting is absolutely finished after at most 12 days (at 70 degrees), but this kit just keeps on truckin'.  Today is Day 15, and there's still some minimal but steady bubble activity visible in the glass carboy...you can't watch the airlock move, but there is some CO2 still being generated.

I certianly don't want to end up with an exploding batch by bottling too soon (these kits include 190g of dextrose for bottling), but I'm also wondering if everything is actually fine and that this will end up being a more completely fermented batch than I'm used to.

Can I go ahead and bottle now as is?  If so, should I cut back a bit on the bottling sugar?  Or should I keep waiting it out until the bubbling completely stops?

Answer (score 6):

Airlock bubbles can mean continued fermentation, or they can just mean there's CO2 coming out of solution.  They're not a reliable indicator.  Take a gravity reading and when you get several consistent readings over a few days, it's done.